# Using jQuery to take the value of an input. Works but the confirm is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to take the value of an input, and if it's true, confirm("Correct!");. It's sorta working. The Confirm is wrong, keeps saying "Correct!" when the answer is wrong and "Incorrect!" when the answer is right. When I said that the correct answer === false, It said everything was true. How do I fix it?
HTML:

```
<input type="textbox" id="best-programmer" placeholder="(e.g. Jonathan)">
      <button id="btn-1">Enter</button><br>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn-1').on("click", function(){
    if ($('#best-programmer').val('Brendon') === true){
      confirm("Correct!");
    } else {
      confirm("Incorrect!");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your if.

When you want to compare the value of the input you do the .val() function.

Like this :

```
if ($('#best-programmer').val() === 'Brendon')
```

If you do .val('something'), the value in the input is changed. As you can see in your fiddle, if you first type : Jonathan, and then submit, the value of the input changes to Brendon.

Answer (score 0):

The method .val() sets or returns a value. You used it to set the value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn-1').on("click", function(){
    if ($('#best-programmer').val() === 'Brendon'){
    confirm("Correct!");
  } else {
    confirm("Incorrect!");
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I have a question, it's to make sure that the answer is correct. I want to use .toUpperCase() to make the value of it capitalized after hitting 'enter.' So far, it's been making my code not working (I was using .val().toUpperCase()). How do you do this?

Comment: toUpperCase() will convert the whole string to upper case. You should check if like this: .val().toUpperCase() === 'BRENDON'. By the way, you sould accept as corret Joel Almeidas answer, as it looks like it solved your issue.

Comment: $('#btn-1').on("click", function(){
    var brendon = $('#best-programmer').val();
    brendon = brendon.toUpperCase();
    if (brendon === 'BRENDON'){
      confirm("Correct!");
    } else {
      confirm("Incorrect!");
    }
    document.getElementById('best-programmer').disabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be replacing the value of the #best-programmer input with 'Brendon' and on success will be true. Instead replace true with 'Brendon' and remove 'Brendon' from the val() like this:

```
if ($('#best-programmer').val() === 'Brendon'){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a common mistake with jQuery val() calls.

var value = $('#selectorid').val();

reads the value and assign this value to the variable value which we can check in equalities, etc., where as

$('#selectorid').val('Brendon');

would set the value of the selected element to the value of "Brendon", regardless of the value it held before.

In your if statement, therefore $('#best-programmer').val('Brendon') is not reading the value of the selected element but setting the value to 'Brendon' each time the button is clicked, even if something other than Brendon is entered. Try using the example code I have modified below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn-1').on("click", function(){
            if ($('#best-programmer').val() == 'Brendon'){
                confirm("Correct!");
            } else {
                confirm("Incorrect!");
            }
        });
    });
```